# How to delete document from a referenced array of documents in doctrine ODM with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a php object mapping to a mongodb document(called Node) with a structure

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

class Node{
    /**
    * @MongoDB\Id
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @MongoDB\String
    */
    protected $domain;

    /**
    * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="NodeItem",cascade=     
    * {"persist"},simple="true")
    */
    protected $items = array();

    //getter and setters below
}
```

And a referenced document called, NodeItem,

```
class NodeItem {

  /**
  * @MongoDB\Id
  */
  protected $id;

  /**
  * @MongoDB\String
  */
  protected $name;

  /**
   * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Node", cascade={"persist"},    
   *  simple="true")
   */
   protected Node;

   //setter and getters 
}
```

As reflected by the annotations above 'Node' references MANY 'NodeItems' stored in a $items array and 'NodeItems' references ONE 'Node'. So those are bi-directional referenced collections.

My Question is how to effectively delete a few 'NodeItem' documents from its collection (based on the array of available ids), so that the deleted NodeItem documents are also deleted from the $items array references in 'Node' (cascaded delete I think is what I am asking for?).

I wrote a function that has code like this :

```
   $qb = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('SomeBundleBundle:NodeItem');
    /*
     * deletes from NodeItem collection
     */
    foreach($NodeItemsArray as $itemId){
        $qb->remove()->field('id')->equals($itemId)->getQuery()->execute();
    }
```

But the above function only deletes the documents from NodeItem collection, but the associated items in the $items array of 'Node' are not deleted. Also, the {cascade:persist} in the annotations doesn't seem to help. The code is implemented in Symfony 2 framework

Some help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve that is with a listener on the onRemove event.

But has mentioned by @jmikola, you'll have to use the $dm->remove() method, and not the QueryBuilder (since it doesn't support events yet).

---

so, **to delete the Item** do:

```
//Get the NodeItem you want in the items array and delete it:
$items = $node->getItems();
$dm->remove($items->get(2)); //Remove the third item as an example
```

---

And **register the event**:

```
class CascadeNodeDeleterListener {
        public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs) {

        $odm = $eventArgs->getDocumentManager(); /* @var $odm DocumentManager */
        $object = $eventArgs->getDocument();
        if($object instanceOf NodeItem) {
                $node = $object->getNode();
                $items = $node->getItems();
                $items->removeElement($object);
                $class = $dm->getClassMetadata(get_class($node));
                $dm->getUnitOfWork()->recomputeSingleDocumentChangeSet($class, $node);
            }

        }
}
```

In `services.yml`:

```
 <service id="listener" class="CascadeNodeDeleterListener">
      <tag name="doctrine.common.event_listener" event="onRemove" />
 </service>
```

See [Doctrine ODM Events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/events.html#implementing-event-listeners) from more info.

Answer (score 0):

Cascade behavior in ODM is only respected by UnitOfWork operations. MongoDB does not natively support cascades and triggers (yet, anyway). In your case, query builder will construct and execute a query like the following:

```
db.node_items.remove({"_id": ObjectId("...")})
```

UnitOfWork is not involved at all (there are no staged operations or flushing) and no cascade is triggered.

On the other hand, say you had a managed `$nodeItem` object. Passing it to `DocumentManager::remove()` would invoke UnitOfWork and cause any referenced documents mapped with `cascade=REMOVE` or `cascade=ALL` to also be removed. Of course, you'd have to call `flush()` to execute the operations in MongoDB.

Based on your current code, the only operation that will be cascaded is `DocumentManager::persist()`. In practice, I assume you'd create a Node, construct and add a few NodeItems to it, and persist the Node (allowing its items to be persisted automatically).

If NodeItems only ever belong to a single Node, you may want to avoid `cascade=REMOVE` and simply do `$nodeItem->getNode()->getItems()->removeElement($nodeItem)` after you remove the `$nodeItem` itself, but before `flush()`.

Also, I noticed you're initializing your collection field to an array. Later on, ODM is going to hydrate this field as a `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\PersistentCollection` instance, which could lead to ambiguity. As a best practice, you should initialize such fields as `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` in your constructor. That way, you can always expect them to be `Collection` instances.